# Trouble unscaling data after predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am working on a project where I am trying to predict mlb player stats from 1970 - 2022. I have 2 datasets, one for batters where I am predicting on 5 stats with 20 features and another for pitchers where I am predicting on 6 stats with 25 features. I am currently working on a Decision Tree Model, but also plan to work with Linear Regression and LSTM models as well.

Prior to initially scaling the dataset I removed the string columns, year, and columns I was using to compare results with.

```
remove_bat_cols = ['Name', 'Tm', 'Year', 'Nxt_BA', 'Nxt_RBI', 'Nxt_HR', 'Nxt_BB', 'Nxt_SO']
remove_pitch_cols = ['Name', 'Tm', 'Year', 'Nxt_ERA', 'Nxt_SO', 'Nxt_WHIP', 'Nxt_BB', 'Nxt_W', 'Nxt_SV']

bat_cols = batting.columns[~batting.columns.isin(remove_bat_cols)]
pitch_cols = pitching.columns[~pitching.columns.isin(remove_pitch_cols)]
```

I then scaled my data

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
batting.loc[:, bat_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(batting[bat_cols])
pitching.loc[:, pitch_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(pitching[pitch_cols])
```

I initially tried to just reverse my steps to unscale

```
batting.loc[:, bat_cols] = scaler.inverse_transform(batting[bat_cols])
pitching.loc[:, pitch_cols] = scaler.inverse_transform(pitching[pitch_cols])
```

But I receive the below error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (26768,29) (31,) (26768,29)
```

I've also tried adding the predicted columns and even tried only predicted columns and receive the same.

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of more research online I found a resolution that worked for me:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/89511/how-to-use-inverse-transform-in-minmaxscaler-for-pred-answer-in-a-matrix

I realized I did not need to unscale the entire dataset so I just went with the predicted columns.

In case anyone is interested in how I coded it:

```
## - BA
batting[['BA_DTR']] = round(batting[['BA_DTR']], 3)

## - RBI
bat_rbi_dtr = batting[['RBI_DTR']]
#scaled from 0 to 165
min = 0
max = 165
bat_rbi_dtr * min + (max - min)

batting['RBI_DTR'] = bat_rbi_dtr.astype(int)


## - HR
bat_hr_dtr = batting[['HR_DTR']]
#scaled from 0 to 73
min = 0
max = 73
bat_hr_dtr * min + (max - min)

batting['HR_DTR'] = bat_hr_dtr.astype(int)

## - BB
bat_bb_dtr = batting[['BB_DTR']]
#scaled from 0 to 232
min = 0
max = 232
bat_bb_dtr * min + (max - min)

batting['BB_DTR'] = bat_bb_dtr.astype(int)

## - SO
bat_so_dtr = batting[['SO_DTR']]
#scaled from 0 to 223
min = 0
max = 223
bat_so_dtr * min + (max - min)

batting['SO_DTR'] = bat_so_dtr.astype(int)
```

If anyone has any better/cleaner options please feel free to still respond